# Calculate degree or angle for source marker rotation using destination latlong

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I used JavaScript  Google Map api, for displaying map,
I have two `markers` with it latlng `Source`, `Destination`.
I have to `rotate` my `source` `marker` direction from the basis of the `destination` `latlng`.

I used the `source` marker `icon` as svg notation path 
here is my code for source icon

```
<script>
var carIcon = {
    path: "M17.402,0H5.643C2.526,0,0,3.467,0,6.584v34.804c0,3.116,2.526,5.644,5.643,5.644h11.759c3.116,0,5.644-2.527,5.644-5.644 V6.584C23.044,3.467,20.518,0,17.402,0z M22.057,14.188v11.665l-2.729,0.351v-4.806L22.057,14.188z M20.625,10.773 c-1.016,3.9-2.219,8.51-2.219,8.51H4.638l-2.222-8.51C2.417,10.773,11.3,7.755,20.625,10.773z M3.748,21.713v4.492l-2.73-0.349 V14.502L3.748,21.713z M1.018,37.938V27.579l2.73,0.343v8.196L1.018,37.938z M2.575,40.882l2.218-3.336h13.771l2.219,3.336H2.575z M19.328,35.805v-7.872l2.729-0.355v10.048L19.328,35.805z",,
    scale: .7,
    strokeColor: '#9c9c9c',
    strokeWeight: .10,
    fillOpacity: 1,
    fillColor: '#C21F25',
    offset: '100%',
    rotation: 50,
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 25) // orig 10,50 back of car, 10,0 front of car, 10,25 center of car
},
</script>
```

i know the above `roation` option to change the marker rotation.

I Want,
Calculate `car marker` degree(angle) for rotation, using the `destination(green)` marker `latlng`.

First image in my current result, and second image in i want this type of result.

[image: current status]
[image: i want like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the heading between two locations using the google maps geometry library:

```
 var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(source, destination);
```

Here is a snippet to demonstrate:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry"></script>
  <script>
    var map;
    var markers = [];
    var carIcon = {
      path: "M17.402,0H5.643C2.526,0,0,3.467,0,6.584v34.804c0,3.116,2.526,5.644,5.643,5.644h11.759c3.116,0,5.644-2.527,5.644-5.644 V6.584C23.044,3.467,20.518,0,17.402,0z M22.057,14.188v11.665l-2.729,0.351v-4.806L22.057,14.188z M20.625,10.773 c-1.016,3.9-2.219,8.51-2.219,8.51H4.638l-2.222-8.51C2.417,10.773,11.3,7.755,20.625,10.773z M3.748,21.713v4.492l-2.73-0.349 V14.502L3.748,21.713z M1.018,37.938V27.579l2.73,0.343v8.196L1.018,37.938z M2.575,40.882l2.218-3.336h13.771l2.219,3.336H2.575z M19.328,35.805v-7.872l2.729-0.355v10.048L19.328,35.805z",
      scale: .7,
      strokeColor: '#9c9c9c',
      strokeWeight: .10,
      fillOpacity: 1,
      fillColor: '#C21F25',
      offset: '100%',
      rotation: 0,
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 25) // orig 10,50 back of car, 10,0 front of car, 10,25 center of car
    };

    function initialize() {
      var losAngeles = new google.maps.LatLng(34.0500, -118.2500);
      var pasadena = new google.maps.LatLng(34.14778, -118.14452);
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: losAngeles,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
      addMarker(losAngeles);
      var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(pasadena, losAngeles);
      addCarIcon(pasadena, heading)
    }

    function addMarker(location) {
      var markerOptions = {
        position: location,
        map: map
      };
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
    }

    function addCarIcon(location, heading) {
      console.log(heading)
      carIcon.rotation = heading;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map,
        draggable: false,
        icon: carIcon
      });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map-canvas" style="width:600px;height:300px"></div>
</body>

</html>
```